# Normal Class, Abstract Class and Interface with same functionality, which one has smallest memory size?

Tags: java

I want to compare the size of normal class, abstract class and interface. They have same 1 name property and 1 callMe method. The detail about them here:

The normal class

```
public class Student {
    public final String name = "";

    public String callMe() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The abstract class

```
public abstract class AStudent {
    public final String name = "";

    public abstract String callMe();
}
```

The interface

```
public interface IStudent {
    public final String name = "";

    public String callMe();
}
```

What is the smallest by memory size? If possible, could you please sort by down-up.

I think the result could be (smallest to biggest): interface, abstract class, normal class. Is that right?

Comment: Strange question. What would an answer help you? Would you choose not to define an interface if it has larger memory usage than an abstract class?

Comment: No, I just want to know the real size of them if they have same everything inside.

Comment: What is the "real size" of a class/abstract class/interface? This makes no sense.

Comment: I mean something like in C++. class Student{....} and we can call sizeof(Student). In java, it is more complex. But the most important, those methods need an instance. Abstract class and interface cannot make an instance. So I cannot check by code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "size". You could take a look at the compiled byte code using the [`javap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html) tool. For the two classes and the interface `javap -sysinfo` shows me these sizes:

- `Student`: 446 bytes
- `AStudent`: 399 bytes
- `IStudent`: 215 bytes

But this is only the static size of the bytecode, not the memory required at runtime. Only `Student` can be instantiated, an abstract class or an interface can not exist on its own at runtime.